# Underline span but not p

Tags: html, css

I have an span that contains a p-tag and text. Now I want to add an underline effect on hover. But I only want to underline the Text, in this case 'Tree', but not the 'Test'. Unfortunately I can not add anything to the 'tree'. I can not remove the underlining in the p-tag with text-decoration: none.

```
<span id="underline">
  <p id="noUnderline">Test</p>
  Tree
</span>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Structurally, you should have your `span` inside your `p`. HTML is very forgiving, but this is the intended hiarachy

Comment: What have you tried exactly to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest put a span around "Tree" and add the effect to that.

<strike>If that's not possible, you could add the effect to the span and remove it from the p-tag. But i'd rather have no effect than doing that</strike> ;)
Edit: I was more enthusiastic, ignore the second idea.

Comment: That was my first idea, but I'm not able to remove the underlining from the p-tag if the span has text-decoration: underline. Maybe you have an idea?

Comment: The answer with the border style for the bottom works pretty good. But why is it not possible to add a tag around the text that should be underlined? That would be a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.

> Text decorations are drawn across descendant text elements. This means that if an element specifies a text decoration, then a child element can't remove the decoration.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration

Answer (score 0):

For this very specific case, and if it is truly not possible to add a span around the text node or to alter the styling of the p element, then you can get the effect with a bottom border - but it's only for specific cases:

```html
<style>
#underline {
  border-style: none none solid none;
}
</style>

<span id="underline">
  <p id="noUnderline">Test</p>
  Tree
</span>
```